# How do you set filename for Webdatarocks default export

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, webdatarocks

As the title suggests i cant for the life of me find a way to give the exported file a name except "Pivot"

The HTML/Vue part only has the Pivot and a select dropdown that filters by date and that works fine, it's only the export that i'm struggling with

```
<template>
    <v-card>
        <v-progress-linear
            v-if="loading"
            class="position-absolute"
            style="z-index: 1"
            color="red"
            height="10"
            indeterminate></v-progress-linear>

        <v-card-title style="text-align:center"> Reports </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text v-if="!loading">
            <v-row>
                <v-col cols="3" offset="1">
                    <v-select
                        v-model="selectedDate"
                        :items="reportdates"
                        label="Period:"
                        item-title="rd_date_label"
                        item-value="rd_date"
                        density="compact"
                        hide-details>
                    </v-select>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
            <br />
            <v-row>
                <Pivot id="pivotid" 
                    ref="pivotref" 
                    height="650px" 
                    :report="report" 
                    :toolbar="toolbar" 
                    :beforetoolbarcreated="beforetoolbarcreated">
                </Pivot>
            </v-row>
        </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
</template>
```

Javascript part with my methods and data structure

```
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import 'webdatarocks/webdatarocks.css'
import Pivot from "../../Common/Pivot.vue";
import '../../Common/webdatarocks.css';

export default {
    name: 'Reports',
    props: {
        curDate: String,
    },
    components: { 
        Pivot
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters (['reportdates', 'worktask']),
    },
    mounted() {
    },
    created() { 
        this.loadingData();
    },
    data() {
        return {
            isAdmin: null,
            loading: false,
            loaded: {
                reportdates: false,
                worktask: false,
            },
            selectedDate: null,
            datachanged: null,
            toolbar: true,
            beforetoolbarcreated: this.customizeToolbar,
            report: {
                dataSource: {
                    data: [],
                },
                formats: [{
                    name: "hours",
                    maxDecimalPlaces: 2,
                    maxSymbols: 20,
                    textAlign: "right"
                }],
                slice: {
                    rows: [{
                            uniqueName: "Employee"
                        }
                        // ,{
                        //     uniqueName: "Date"
                        // },
                    ],
                    columns: [
                        {
                            uniqueName: "Client"
                        },
                        {
                            uniqueName: "[Measures]"
                        },],
                    measures: [{
                        uniqueName: "Hours",
                        aggregation: "sum",
                        format: "hours"
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    grid: {
                        type: "compact",
                        title: "",
                        showFilter: true,
                        showHeaders: true,
                        showTotals: true,
                        showGrandTotals: "on",
                        showHierarchies: true,
                        showHierarchyCaptions: true,
                        showReportFiltersArea: true
                    },
                    configuratorActive: false,
                    configuratorButton: true,
                    showAggregations: true,
                    showCalculatedValuesButton: true,
                    drillThrough: true,
                    showDrillThroughConfigurator: true,
                    sorting: "on",
                    datePattern: "dd/MM/yyyy",
                    dateTimePattern: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                    saveAllFormats: false,
                    showDefaultSlice: true,
                    defaultHierarchySortName: "asc",
                },
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        reportdates() {
            this.loaded.reportdates = true;
            let fdate = this.reportdates.find(r => r.rd_date_label === this.curDate);
            this.selectedDate = fdate.rd_date;
            this.checkLoading();
        },
        worktask() {
            this.loaded.worktask = true;
            this.checkLoading();
            //console.log('worktask: ' + this.worktask.length);
            this.report.dataSource.data = this.getJSONData();

        },
        async selectedDate() {
            //console.log('selectedDate: ' + this.selectedDate);
            let fdate = this.reportdates.find(r => r.rd_date_label === this.curDate);

            let tUserEmail = window.Laravel.user.email;

             let tUserId = window.Laravel.user.id;

             if(window.Laravel.user.role === "USR"){

                if (fdate.rd_date == this.selectedDate) {
                this.report.dataSource.data = [];
                this.$store.dispatch('fetchWorkTaskReportDataUser', { rdate : this.selectedDate, tUserEmail : tUserEmail, });
                } else {
                    let dstr = new Date(this.selectedDate).toISOString().slice(0, 7);
                    const params = Object.assign({}, this.$route.params);
                    params.curDate = dstr;
                    await this.$router.push({ params });
                    this.$router.go();
                }

             }else{

                if (fdate.rd_date == this.selectedDate) {
                this.report.dataSource.data = [];
                this.$store.dispatch('fetchWorkTaskReportData', { rdate : this.selectedDate, tUserEmail : tUserEmail, });
                } else {
                    let dstr = new Date(this.selectedDate).toISOString().slice(0, 7);
                    const params = Object.assign({}, this.$route.params);
                    params.curDate = dstr;
                    await this.$router.push({ params });
                    this.$router.go();
                }

             }


            // if (fdate.rd_date == this.selectedDate) {
            //     this.report.dataSource.data = [];
            //     this.$store.dispatch('fetchWorkTaskReportDataUser', { rdate : this.selectedDate, tUserEmail : tUserEmail, });
            // } else {
            //     let dstr = new Date(this.selectedDate).toISOString().slice(0, 7);
            //     const params = Object.assign({}, this.$route.params);
            //     params.curDate = dstr;
            //     await this.$router.push({ params });
            //     this.$router.go();
            // }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        loadingData() {
            this.loading = true;

            // let tUserId = window.Laravel.user.id;

            // if(window.Laravel.user.role === "ADM"){
            //     console.log("Admin");
            //     this.$store.dispatch('fetchReportDates',{
            //     tUserId : tUserId,
            // });

            // }else{
            //     console.log("User");
            //     this.$store.dispatch('fetchReportDatesUser',{
            //     tUserId : tUserId,
            // })}

            this.$store.dispatch('fetchReportDates',{
                // tUserId : tUserId,
            })
        },
        checkLoading() {
            this.loading = !(this.loaded.reportdates && this.loaded.worktask);
        },
        getText(item) {
            return item;
        },
        customizeToolbar(toolbar) {
            var tabs = toolbar.getTabs();
            toolbar.getTabs = function() {
                delete tabs[0];
                delete tabs[1];
                delete tabs[2];
                delete tabs[7];
                return tabs;
            }
        },
        getJSONData() {
            return this.worktask
            for(let r=0; r < this.worktask.length; r++){
                returns.push(this.worktask[r]); 
            }
            return returns;
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by customizing the default tabs from the Toolbar and using the `exporTo()` API call. For example, here's how you can change the name of the exported PDF file:

```
function customizeToolbar(toolbar) {
    // get all tabs
  let tabs = toolbar.getTabs();
  toolbar.getTabs = function() {
    let exportTab = tabs.find(tab => tab.id == "wdr-tab-export");
    if (!exportTab) return tabs;
    let exportToPdfTab = exportTab.menu.find(tab => tab.id == "wdr-tab-export-pdf");
    exportToPdfTab.handler = () => {
      this.pivot.exportTo("pdf", {
        filename: "custom-name" // set the necessary name
      });
    }
    return tabs;
  }
}
```

Please check the following CodePen: https://codepen.io/webdatarocks/pen/QWxYLRy?editors=1010